# Installing Laravel on windows 8.1 using composer

Tags: php, laravel, cygwin, windows-8.1, composer-php

Please  I would be very happy if anyone could help me on this, for the past two days I have been trying to install laravel using composer on windows 8.1, through the cygwin terminal and it seems to be outputting errors; one on the terminal and the other when i view my laravel project on the localhost browser. I will be very glad if I could get any help from anyone. 
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if you're using `Command Prompt` or `Powershell`?

Comment: Yes! I used the powershell tool and it worked, I believe the cygwin was not too compatible with the Windows 8.1. Thanks a million Marwelln and Skynet. God bless you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Git Bash from the [Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/) project, for the best results, especially if you're familiar with Linux/Unix.  I can confirm this works on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Powershell was quite slow though. So I will say Git Bash is much prefered!